# Can't change the language in microsoft cognitive services spellchecker

Tags: spell-checking, azure-cognitive-services, bing

Here is the Microsoft Python example of using spellchecker API:

```
import http.client, urllib.parse, json

text = 'Hollo, wrld!'

data = {'text': text}

# NOTE: Replace this example key with a valid subscription key.
key = 'MY_API_KEY'

host = 'api.cognitive.microsoft.com'
path = '/bing/v7.0/spellcheck?'
params = 'mkt=en-us&mode=proof'

headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': key,
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

# The headers in the following example 
# are optional but should be considered as required:
#
# X-MSEdge-ClientIP: 999.999.999.999  
# X-Search-Location: lat: +90.0000000000000;long: 00.0000000000000;re:100.000000000000
# X-MSEdge-ClientID: <Client ID from Previous Response Goes Here>

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(host)
body = urllib.parse.urlencode(data)
conn.request ("POST", path + params, body, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
output = json.dumps(json.loads(response.read()), indent=4)
print (output)
```

And it works well for mkt=en-us. But if I try to change it, for example to 'fr-FR'. It always answers me with a blank response to any input text.

```
{
    "_type": "SpellCheck",
    "flaggedTokens": []
}
```

Has anybody encountered the similar problem? May it be connected with my trial api key (though they do not mention that trial supports only English)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've found out what the problem was. 'mode=proof' — advanced spellchecker currently available only if 'mkt=en-us' (for some Microsoft reasons it does not available even if 'mkt=en-uk'). For all other languages, you should use 'mode=spell'.

The main difference between 'proof' and 'spell' is described like this:

> The Spell mode finds most spelling mistakes but doesn't find some of the grammar errors that Proof catches (for example, capitalization and repeated words).